# SQLPlus is throwing client hostname issue ORA-24454, whereas I can telnet to hostname successfully

Tags: oracle, macos, sqlplus, hostname

I'm trying to connect to the **oracle** database via **sqlplus** hosted on a remote instance using command like this `sqlplus user@hostname.com:port/SchemaName`. And on typing password it throws weird client host issue. See the screenshot below.

**The question is which host name its expecting me to put inside `/etc/hosts`?**

[image]

Whereas I can `telnet` successfully to same instance without any issues. By the way I'm on `MacOS 10.15.7`.

[image]

Oracle clients were installed using this [link](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/macos-intel-x86-downloads.html). Can be seen from the screenshot below.

[image]

The installation was moved to the appropriate folder.

[image]

The `$PATH` was also exported to `~/.bash_profile` file

[image]

Comment: You need to set 127.0.1.1 to your local hostname in `/etc/hosts`.  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167477/ora-24454-client-host-name-is-not-set-when-connecting-from-ubuntu-instance-on

Comment: SQL*Plus command looks strange to me. Shouldn't it be `sqlplus username/password@hostname.com:port/service_name`?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3027266

Comment: Thanks guys I resolved it and shared the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by the solution mentioned on this [link](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/79#issuecomment-412006628).

Using `hostname` command I was able to find host name of my machine, which was required to make a successful connection to the Oracle.

The screenshot below explains the process

[image]

The hostname entry looks like below

[image]

Comment: Again: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) (also valid for answers) :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the nice information